# Update SQL multiple row value in single query with multiple column combination

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuUtc.png)

I have table with these datas, after do some operations I want to update flag value from 0 to 1 based on the two columns value code and id

```
update table set flag = 1 where code = 'ABC' and id = 10000

update table set flag = 1 where code = 'DEF' and id = 10001

update table set flag = 1 where code = 'GHI' and id = 10002

update table set flag = 1 where code = 'ABC' and id = 10001
```

I can do like this with foreach But I want to update using single query
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please update your question to include your example data as a markdown table or CREATE and INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

`UPDATE table SET flat = 1 WHERE (code = 'ABC' and id = 10000) OR (code = 'DEF' and id = 10001) OR (code = 'GHI' and id = 10002)`

Comment: In this case [operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) works _with you_ but don't get into the habit of writing queries like this. Always include the parentheses, as this will get you into trouble!

Comment: You should indeed add parenthesis, I am pretty sure I typed them while making my answer but somehow they weren't posted